Google Appscript VLOOKUP and output to HTML
I have an HTML form with only one field: "studentID".
<div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <form id="idChecker">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID studente</label>
        <input name="studentId" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci ID Studente" class="metro-input" />
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
        <button class="button success">Check ID</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

I need the form button to trigger two functions:

Log the ID and timestamp on a sheet called "Log" for which I placed this function acceptData() in my code.gs, which is working properly:

function acceptData(formData){
  console.log(formData)
  formData.studentId

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Log")
  ws.appendRow([Date(),formData.studentId])
  
}


Perform a VLOOKUP in another sheet ("Database") of the same document and return the found value on the HTML page as form's confirmation message.

So, basically, when someone inputs a student ID and submits the form it should return the student's name connected to that ID while registering the fact that that ID has been searched.
Hope you can help me with the VLOOKUP thing.

Please focus on one problem.



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#idChecker').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from being submitted automatically
    var formData = {
      'studentId': $('input[name=studentId]').val()
    };
    
    // Call the acceptData() function from Google Apps Script
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(studentName) {
      // Create the confirmation message using the returned student name
      var confirmationMessage = "Student not found.";
      if (studentName !== "Student not found") {
        confirmationMessage = "Student name: " + studentName;
      }
      $('#confirmationMessage').text(confirmationMessage);
    }).acceptData(formData);
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Student ID Checker</title>
  <!-- Include jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <form id="idChecker">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="studentId">Student ID</label>
          <input name="studentId" type="text" placeholder="Enter Student ID" class="metro-input" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="button success">Check ID</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Area to display confirmation message -->
  <div id="confirmationMessage"></div>

  <!-- Include JavaScript file containing Google Apps Script functions -->
  <script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbycGBJLx_Q1eJDitpHwQ2PV-ZIamjg3i4tNmV8WbeE/exec"></script>
</body>
</html>




Thank you for your answer, by the way I don't understand which part of this code contains the function for finding the match of 'studentID' in the google sheet document. Could you please explain your code?
